# How can I create a function that I could use to modify text displayed?

Tags: angularjs

I am using this code:

```
    $scope.indexChar = function (index) {
        return String.fromCharCode(65 + index);
    };
```

Is there a way I can create a common function shared in my application to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try angular [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)

```
app.filter('indexChar', function() {
    return function(index) {
      return String.fromCharCode(65 + index);
    };
  });
```

- Use inside template with syntax like this: `{{ $index | indexChar}}`
- Inject to controller to use with `<filterName>Filter` syntax, in this case is  `indexCharFilter` and use it like this: `console.log("Use in controller:" + indexCharFilter(1));`

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/texqgwe3gL9arMu0CtBs?p=preview)