# Calling controller function from element attribute

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

how can I call a controller function from html attribute. For example:

Controller function:

```
$scope.foo = function(id)
{
    return id+1;
}
```

And here is the html:

```
<div ng-repeat obj in arr id="foo(obj.id)"></div>
```

This way I am getting `...id=foo(obj.id)` instead of `...id="2"` (if obj.id is equal 1).

Thanks!

Comment: try `id="{{foo(obj.id)}}"`

Comment: you would normally attach it to an event or dump it into the DOM with {{}}... what's the purpose of your code?

Comment: I have some date I am getting from my server, I wish to change it format this way (`changeFormat(obj.date)`)

Comment: if you need to format date to display, the correct way to do it is using angular filter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432292/how-can-i-create-a-function-that-i-could-use-to-modify-text-displayed/22432327#22432327

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to call angular rendering you need to had {{  }}. Try this: `id="{{foo(obj.id)}}"`